# struts 1.2 - bean message display in lower case

Tags: jsp, struts-1, struts-tags

I am using struts 1.2 in my project and need to iterate the list item in the JSP, get each item and convert that item in to lowercase. Please refer the code below.

```
<logic:iterate id="cityData" name="cityList" >
<p>
    List Messages <bean:message name="cityData" property="cityName"/>
</p>
</logic:iterate>
```

I want to display the cityName in lower case. Can anybody have any idea about this?

Thanks
AK

Comment: That kind of logic belongs in the controller layer.

Comment: but it is not working if we implement in control layer. It is displayed as ???label.name.cityname.???.

Comment: Then you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Can you please provide some samples

Comment: Sample of what?

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `<bean:define/>` instead of `<bean:message />`

```
<logic:iterate id="cityData" name="cityList" >
 <bean:define id = "name" name="cityData" property="cityName" type = "java.lang.String"/>
 <p>
  List Messages <%=name.toLowerCase())%>
 </p>
</logic:iterate>
```

Comment: Besides using scriptlets being generally frowned upon, why bother with `out.println` when you can just use `<%= ... %>`?

Comment: Sure, that will do